# Unity Wall Elements in 2D RPG

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to create a top-down viewed 2D RPG. But sadly I am already failing at creating movement-impairing walls. Here are the components of the player (char) and the wall:

[image]

But now if I try to run into the box collider of the wall element I dont get blocked as I expected. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** updated the image

Answer (score 1):

You need to add collider to your character, because collisions can be crecognized between two colliders. Also, there is no need to put `Rigidbody2D` on Wall, Unity requires `Rigidbody2D` on one of collided objects, so if you have Rigidbody2D on Character there is no need to got it on wall too.

Comment: Okay I added one, but how do I set the wall as impassable?

Comment: It should work like you want i think. Can you describe situation with more details? What is wrong now: e.g: character can pass through the wall?

Comment: Sorry for mess, but i think about one more thing, collider size on Wall, i think better is to set collider as size 1x1 and change scale in transform component of object. Also ?Unity sometimes got problems with collision detection when collider is too small (eg. thin and long).

Comment: Nono, the collision is detected properly (i checked with Debug.Log()) but the player can still walk through the wall freely. Do I have to add anything else to the wall object?

Comment: Did you removed `Rigidbody2D` component from wall object? If not you can check remove it or try to "check" `Is Kinematic` on Rigidbody2D on wall object. I think there could be a problem that the character simpli pushed wall object but its only a thought.

Comment: I did remove it, I think unity doesnt see this wall as solid.

Comment: Can you edit a question and add screenshot of how currently looks inspector on both objects? Strange thing is that this should work fine, looks like we missing something :|

Comment: Thats because the wall doesnt have a graphic. The offset of the collider isnt 0;0 as you can see

Comment: GFX on object isn't necssesery. But one more thing: are you sure that you didnt walking inside a collider?

Comment: What? Of course i am walking _into_ the collider, making this unable was the purpose of the question.

Comment: Ok, so that was a misunderstanding. There is no possibility to collide "walls" of collider from inside. You have to create e.g four objects and make every single object will be a single wall of box. In Unity collision detection working only from outside of colider.

Comment: Apparently you still don't understand me :/ the problem is that i **can't** create walls that block the players movement, for whatever reason that is.

Comment: Really strange thing. But one more: about player movement script. Can you show us the code? Or can you tell if movement is based on velocity on `Rigidbody2D` componenet or on `transform.position`? And if the movement parts of code are in `FixedUpdate()`?

Comment: OK, I fixed it!! I put changed the transform.Translate() to rigidbody2d.velocity. Thanks alot! But one more thing. When I first run into the wall the player walks up onto it a bit.

Comment: Collision detection sometims is not very accurate, especialy when object moving fast. Try to use smaller size of objects, smaller speed etc.